React: Easy way to add an item to a dynamic list and make it selected
Let's say we have a List react component (any generic list) which has items (comes from back-end via HTTP call) and selectedIndex.
If there is a button that adds a new item to the list (via back-end call and then get the list), how can it also make the new item selected? Problem is, when I add item to the list, it calls setState(newList) but I can't call setSelectedIndex(newList.length-1) right after, because initial setState is not done yet. And also, react hooks, don't support a callback after setState is done.
Example code:
...
const [items, setItems] = useState([])
const [idx, setIdx] = useState()
useEffect(() => {
  getDataFromServer().then(setItems)
}, [])
const add = () => {
  serverAddItem("test item").then((newList) => {
  setItems(newList);
  setIdx(newList.length-1); //THIS FAILS!
});
};

return <>
<List options={items} selectedIndex={idx} />
<button onClick={add} />
</>


When I want to change selected index of the list to my item, it is not there at that point. It will be there when my setItems call is finished, after which I won't have access to the index I want to set.
P.S.:The problem with setIdx(newList.length-1) is that, when it runs, it tries to set selected index to 5 (for example), but list has only 4 items yet, and its state is not updated. So, the update to selected index does not change anything and in the UI, user sees list updated, but with no selected item.

Why, how, or in what way, is setIdx(newList.length - 1); failing? Please [edit] to describe the specific issue or problem you have in clearer detail. setIdx(newList.length - 1); seems fine to me since you are using the value that items will be updated to instead of some stale closure of it. If I had to guess there's an issue created downstream in the List component? Can you [edit] to include all relevant code you are working with as well?

Thanks @DrewReese. The problem is, calling setIdx tries to set index to something that does not exist in the list items yet. Because setState is not done yet.

That really shouldn't be a problem because all enqueued React state updates are processed asynchronously. Please explain where and how enqueueing both state updates causes a problem.

You have a list of 3 items.
update 1: Add X to the end of the list
update 2: Select 4th item in the list.
If these two run async then, in UI you won't see 4th item selected

If both state updates are processed (I don't see any way for them not to unless an exception is thrown) then the end result should be that the component rerenders and both updated states are available. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code that demonstrates the specific issue or problem you have?
